# Ruby project help. Can't get saved instances from array

Tags: ruby

TLDR I am working on a project that creates instances using an API. I want to be able to recall all of my instances but can't figure out how. I'm relatively new to Ruby and programming in general so I hope I'm explaining everything well enough. Here's my code.

```
class Suggestion
    attr_accessor :type, :participants 
    attr_reader :activity, :price, :link, :key, :accessibility

    @@all = []

    def initialize(type, participants)
        @type = type
        @participants = participants
        # @activity = []
        # @price = price
        # @key = key
        # @accessibility = accessibility
         @@all << self
    end

    # def save
    #     @@all << self
    # end

    def self.all
        @@all
    end

    # def events
    #     @@all.map
    # end
    
    def list_events
        # binding.pry
        Suggestion.all.map #{|event| [:activity, :type, :participants, :price, :link, :key, :accessibility]}
    end

end
```

any and all help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following class definition, where I've made `@all` a *class instance variable*, rather than a class variable. Use of the former is generally preferred over use of the latter.

```
class Suggestion
  attr_accessor :type, :participants

  @all = []

  class << self
    attr_accessor :all
  end

  def initialize(type, participants)
    @type = type
    @participants = participants
    self.class.all << self
  end 

  def list_events
    self.class.all.map do |instance|
      { type: instance.type, participants: instance.participants }
    end 
  end

  def self.list_events
    all.map do |instance|
      { type: instance.type, participants: instance.participants }
    end 
  end
end
```

The snippet

```
class << self
  attr_accessor :all
end
```

creates a read-write accessor for `@all`. `class << self` causes `self` to be changed to `Suggestion`'s singleton class. If desired you could replace this with

```
superclass.public_send(:attr_accessor, :all)
```

---

Let's try it.

```
Suggestion.all
  #=> []
```

```
s1 = Suggestion.new(1, ['Bob', 'Sally'])
  #=> #<Suggestion:0x00007fc677084888 @type=1, @participants=["Bob", "Sally"]>
Suggestion.all
  #=> [#<Suggestion:0x00007fc677084888 @type=1, @participants=["Bob", "Sally"]>]
```

```
s2 = Suggestion.new(2, ['Ronda', 'Cliff'])
  #<Suggestion:0x00007fc677b577b0 @type=2, @participants=["Ronda", "Cliff"]>
Suggestion.all
  #=> [#<Suggestion:0x00007fc677084888 @type=1, @participants=["Bob", "Sally"]>,
  #    #<Suggestion:0x00007fc677b577b0 @type=2, @participants=["Ronda", "Cliff"]>]
```

```
s3 = Suggestion.new(3, ['Weasel', 'Isobel'])
  #=> #<Suggestion:0x00007fc677077598 @type=3, @participants=["Weasel", "Isobel"]>
Suggestion.all
  #=> [#<Suggestion:0x00007fc677084888 @type=1, @participants=["Bob", "Sally"]>,
  #    #<Suggestion:0x00007fc677b577b0 @type=2, @participants=["Ronda", "Cliff"]>,
  #    #<Suggestion:0x00007fc677077598 @type=3, @participants=["Weasel", "Isobel"]>]
```

```
s1.list_events
  #=> [{:type=>1, :participants=>["Bob", "Sally"]},
  #    {:type=>2, :participants=>["Ronda", "Cliff"]},
  #    {:type=>3, :participants=>["Weasel", "Isobel"]}]
```

```
Suggestion.list_events
  #=> [{:type=>1, :participants=>["Bob", "Sally"]},
  #    {:type=>2, :participants=>["Ronda", "Cliff"]},
  #    {:type=>3, :participants=>["Weasel", "Isobel"]}]
```

I included `Suggestion#instance` to show how an instance can access (read or write) the class instance variable `@all`.

Comment: That makes sense thank you. A new question. What if what I am returning from my API is a hash with specific key/value pairs?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question.

Comment: My api returns hash instances with key-value pairs

Comment: I presume you mean one of your methods returns an array of hashes, but I don't see any such method. Note that the single line in your method `list_events` needs to be `Suggestion.all.map {|event| [event.activity, event.type, event.participants, event.price, event.link, event.key, event.accessibility]}`.

Comment: I revised my answer in an attempt to address my understanding of your question. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

### What Already Works

I may be misunderstanding your issue, but it seems like your code mostly works as-is. I refactored it a little to make it a little easier to see what's going on, but your basic approach of self-registration with a class variable during object initialization seems sound. Consider:

```rb
class Suggestion
  @@all = []

  def initialize(type, participants)
      @type = type
      @participants = participants
      @@all << self
  end 

  def self.all
      @@all
  end 
end
```

```rb
s1 = Suggestion.new :foo, %w[Alice Bob]
#=> #<Suggestion:0x00007f9671154578 @participants=["Alice", "Bob"], @type=:foo>

s2 = Suggestion.new :bar, %w[Charlie Dana]
#=> #<Suggestion:0x00007faed7113900 @participants=:bar, @type=:foo>

Suggestion.all
#=>
[#<Suggestion:0x00007f9671154578 @participants=["Alice", "Bob"], @type=:foo>,
 #<Suggestion:0x00007f9671089058
  @participants=["Charlie", "Dana"],
  @type=:bar>]
```

### What Might Need Improvement

You probably just need class or instance methods that "do a thing" with each instance (or selected elements from specific instances) stored in *@@all*. For example:

```rb
# print the object ID of each instance of Suggestion
Suggestion.all.map { |suggestion| suggestion.object_id }
#=> [240, 260]
```

You might also want to use [Array#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-select) to extract specific instances that meet defined criteria, or [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map) to do something with your matching instances. For example:

```rb
# re-open the class to add some getter methods
class Suggestion
  attr_reader :type, :participants
end

# only operate on instances of a given type
Suggestion.all.select { |s| s.type == :foo }
#=> [#<Suggestion:0x00007f9671154578 @participants=["Alice", "Bob"], @type=:foo>]

# invoke Suggestion#participants on matching instances
Suggestion.all.map { |s| s.participants if s.type == :bar }.compact
#=> [["Charlie", "Dana"]]
```

As long as you have a collection through which you can iterate (e.g. your class' *@@all* Array) you can filter, map, or otherwise operate on some or all of your instances at need. There are certainly more complex approaches, but I'd strive to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the response. I tried what you suggested and it still doesn't work. I wish I could be more clear or even show you exactly what I'm working on. I'm so lost

Comment: I don't even get an empty array back. For some reason It can't find it or something.