# My instances aren't saving for some reason in Ruby

Tags: ruby, api

I posted a similar question to the same problem. I am trying to return an array of all instances initialized from an API. I have a cli, and api, and custom class that handles initialization. I have used binding.pry to look at what is going on before i request to see my array (it would return nothing when it hit in my cli), and it shows up empty. I guess what I am trying to say is that I can't figure out why they aren't saving.
[my cli][1]

class Cli

```
def run
    puts "Welcome to the I'm Bored app!"
    api = Api.new()
    input = nil
    while input != "exit"
        puts "How would you like to generate your event?"
        puts "You can generate by type, number of participants, or random!"
        puts "Types include education, recreational, social, diy, charity, cooking, relaxation, music, or busywork."
        puts "Participants can range from 0-5 number you like."
        puts "To generate a totally random event, type 'random'"
        puts "To see all events made so far, type 'events'."
        puts "To quit, type 'exit'."
        # puts "How would you like to generate your event?"
            input = gets.strip.downcase

            if input == "type"
            puts
            puts "Please select education, recreational, social, diy, charity, cooking, relaxation, music, or busywork."
            input = gets.strip.downcase
            puts
            api.event_by_type(input)
            puts
            end
        

            if input == "participants"
            puts
            puts "Please enter your number of participants."
            input = gets.strip.downcase
            puts
            api.event_by_participants(input)
            puts
            end

            if input == "random"
            puts
            puts "Let's roll those dice!"
            puts
            api.event_by_random("activity")
            puts
            end

            if input == "events"
            puts
            puts "Here are your created events"
            puts
            #binding.pry
            Api.each do |key,value|       # map would work just as well, but not needed
                my_hash[key] = some_new_value    
              end
            # puts Api.all.each do |hash| 
            #     #hash.each do |key,value| 
            #       puts hash.type #(key + ': ' + value) 
            #     #end
              end
            puts
            # end
            # Api.all.map
            end
            
          if input == "exit"
            puts
            puts "Take care!"
            puts
            exit
        end     

        # if input != "types" && != "participants" && != "random" && != "events" && != "exit"
        #     input = gets.strip.downcase
        #     puts "I think you mispelled something. Try again."
        #     puts
        # end
    end
end
```

[my api][2]

```
class Api
attr_accessor :url

@@all = []


def initialize()
    @url = "http://www.boredapi.com/api/" #does not work for some reason. returns empty. works fine with test in im-bored.???
end

 def self.all
     @@all
 end

def event_by_random(random)
    # http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/
    req_url="#{@url}#{random}/"
    # 'puts req_url' # Test to make sure I still get the right URL
    data = HTTParty.get(req_url) 
    @@all << data
    puts data
end

def event_by_type(type)
    # http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/
    req_url="#{@url}activity?type=#{type}"
    puts req_url # Test to make sure I still get the right URL
    data = HTTParty.get(req_url) 
    puts data
end

def event_by_participants(participants)
    # http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/
    req_url="#{@url}activity?participants=#{participants}"
    # puts req_url # Test to make sure I still get the right URL
    data = HTTParty.get(req_url) 
    puts data
end
```

end

[my custom ][3]

```
class Suggestion
 attr_accessor :type, :participants 
# attr_reader :activity, :price, :link, :key, :accessibility
@@all = []

  def initialize(type, participants)
      @type = type
      @participants = participants
      @@all << self
  end 

  def self.all
      @@all
  end 
end
```

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: I fixed it. is that better?

Comment: It wasn't saving in my custom, so I tried in my api and that didn't work either.

Comment: Still a little mangled, but much better.

Comment: Tip: Don't lean on class variables (`@@`) so much, they confuse the boundary between class and instance.

Comment: sorry about that. can you elaborate? I'm still pretty new to ruby

Comment: Related question from OP: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66093842/1301972

Comment: It's a bad habit to get into. Normally you should have straight up instances manipulating instance variables, not leaning on class variables like this. For example, just use a regular Array or Set to store those, as in `self.all` can return `ALL = [ ]` and then `self.class.all << self` within the instance to auto-register it, but even auto-registering is a bit of a miss. That should be done via a factory method of some kind. Hard to explain succinctly, but I'd say just start simple and build up, don't try and make your classes do too much.

Comment: What you have here looks like a primitive form of *Dependency Injection* so you've got some good ideas, they're just not quite in the right shape.

Comment: What is `Api.each` supposed to do? This is kinda a lot of code, I would recommend trying to reproduce the problem in a standalone example

Comment: Please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.